# how i can prevent multiple time connected to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, global-variables

here is my code

**pdo.php**

```
class Connection {  
   public function __construct() {  
      $this->connect ($db);  
   }  
private function connect($db) {  
    try {  
        if (! $db){  
                  $this->db = new PDO ( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Shopping;charset=utf8', 'xxxx', 'xxxxx' );  
                  echo 'Connected';  
                  return $this->db;  
        }  
        catch ( PDOException $conError ) {  
        echo 'failed to connect DB' . $conError->getMessage ();  
    }  
 }  
}
```

**product.php**

```
class ProductInsert extends Connection {  //here my function is called multiple times 
    function __construct() {  
         parent::__construct($db);  
    }    
    public function prdInsert(.....)  
    {  ........}
```

here my problem is database connection is opened multiple time. when ever i am calling the productInsert() then database connection is opened how i can prevent this

Comment: you need to close your db connection after you use it.

Comment: Thanks but i think  it will be burden on the database, because my program calls productInsert() so many times

Comment: why you are extending connection class to write functions ? db connection is made in construct which is being called every time

Comment: @wordpresser without extending connection how i can access my $db variable in my function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution
**pdo.php**

```
class Connection {
// Declare instance  
private static $instance = NULL;  
// the constructor is set to private so so nobody can create a new instance using new
private function __construct() {
// maybe set the db name here later 
}
// Return DB instance or create intitial connection @return object (PDO) @access public
public static function getInstance() {
    if (! self::$instance) {
        self::$instance = new PDO ( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Shopping;charset=utf8', 'root', 'vss0ftech' );
        self::$instance->setAttribute ( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        echo 'connected';
    } else
        echo 'connection is already existed';
    return self::$instance;     
}
// Like the constructor, we make __clone private so nobody can clone the instance
PRIVATE FUNCTION __CLONE() {
}
}
```

**product.php**

here we can call the method as like this

```
class ProductInsert {  
    public function prdInsert(.....) {  
        $result_By_Vendor_And_Title = Connection::getInstance ()->query ( "select * from........)  
     }  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Do not extend your application class from database class.

This is your main problem.
They are too different classes having nothing in common.
So you have to just use your db object as a *property*.

Connection class is also useless at the moment, as it's just a leaky disguise for the PDO.

So, just create raw PDO object and then pass it in the constructor of product

```
class ProductInsert
{
    function __construct(PDO $db)
    {  
        $this->db = $db;  
    }    
    public function prdInsert(.....)  
}
```

And for goodness sake, **learn to indent your code.**

Comment: Thanks but till now also i am getting notice: undefined var db can u elaborate please

Comment: **You have to create raw PDO object and then pass it in the constructor of product**. `$procuct = new ProductInsert($pdo);`

Comment: Since you were talking about `is-a` relationship, you might want to note the **Liskov Substitution Principle** for him. However +1

Comment: @DaveJust how it is applicable, if product is by no means a subtype of DB?

Comment: No, I didn't mean current example, I meant your point about `is-a/has-a` relationships, which is part of **LSP**, and which is obviously correct. I'm just saying there's a name for the stuff you were talking about :) (LSP)

Comment: @DaveJust ah I see now, thanks. Yeah, I am quite ignorant in the proper naming.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Connection {  
        public function __construct($db) {  
        return $this->connect($db);  
        }  
        private function connect($db) {  
        try {  
        if (! $db){  
        $db = new PDO ( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Shopping;charset=utf8', 'xxxx', 'xxxxx' );  
        echo 'new connection';  
        }
        return $db;  
        }  
        catch ( PDOException $conError ) {  
        echo 'failed to connect DB' . $conError->getMessage ();  
        }    

        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks . i have tried this one it shows Notice: Undefined property: ProductInsert::$db

Comment: what is $db variable about? Can you just remove it from your code?

Comment: $db variable is a PDO object , without this one(PDO Object) how i can move forward(like write quries in db) ?

Comment: how about referring to db property ($something->db)? Could you give more code, it'd be easier to show?

Comment: Actually my $db = new pdo(....) ,this $db object is used to globally and it is calling one time only in different files how i can do this

Comment: try the modified variant

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39033/discussion-between-durgaprasad-and-cur4so)